# How can I detect if a widget will overflow its constraints before it is rendered?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a [`PageView`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PageView-class.html) and I want to use it to show an indefinite amount of widgets in columns. I'm trying to add widgets to a column until it would overflow, and then build the next page beginning with the widget that would have overflowed.

[image: Diagram of problem]

So far, this is what I've hacked together in an effort to get something working:

```
class OverflowSliverChildDelegate extends SliverChildDelegate {
  OverflowSliverChildDelegate({
    @required this.itemBuilder,
  }) : assert(itemBuilder != null),
       super();

  /// Used to build individual items to slot into pages.
  final IndexedWidgetBuilder itemBuilder;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, int index) {
    return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (context, constraints) {
        // todo: handle this better
        if (remainingHeight <= 0) throw Error();

        var itemIndex = 0;
        return PageView.builder(
          itemBuilder: (context, pageIndex) {
            final remainingHeight = constraints.maxHeight;
            return Column(
              // todo: move this generator to a separate method
              children: () sync* {
                // Build widgets until we run out of vertical space.
                while (remainingHeight > 0) {
                  // todo: layout widget and get its height
                  final widget = itemBuilder(context, itemIndex++);

                  // remainingHeight -= widget.height

                  yield widget;
                }
              }(),
            );
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

If I was only concerned with text, I could use a `TextPainter` to layout the text and get the height. Is there a way to do this for arbitrary widgets (which may or may not have children of their own)?

---

**Update**

After looking into the `Offstage` widget, I tried this but Flutter is asserting that I don't call the `size` getter from outside the object. I felt so close to a solution too.

```
          while (remainingHeight > 0) {
              final widget = itemBuilder(context, itemIndex++);

              final renderObj = ConstrainedBox(
                child: widget,
                constraints: constraints.copyWith(
                  maxHeight: remainingHeight,
                ),
              ).createRenderObject(context);

              renderObj.layout(constraints);

              remainingHeight -= renderObj.size.height;

              if (remainingHeight > 0) {
                yield widget;
              }
            }
```

Comment: I just found the `Offstage` widget. https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Offstage-class.html I'll write up an answer if this solves my problem.

Comment: Now looking into `MultiChildLayoutDelegate`. I'll continue to update the question with my findings and will post an answer if I find a solution. https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/MultiChildLayoutDelegate-class.html

Comment: Upvote for the ongoing effort!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up digging into Flutter's source code for the sliver list (essentially the backend for the `ListView` widget) and I was able to figure out how it decided when it had enough children to fill the viewport and the "cache extent".

I've started a fresh Flutter project in order to try different approaches but I've cleaned it up a little and published it to the pub.dev: https://pub.dev/packages/overflow_page_view

The result is a `PageView` which builds a `CustomScrollView` for each page. I've straight-up copied the code for the `RenderSliver` stuff from the Flutter source and changed the parts where it lays out its children. Ideally, I would have liked to have found a way to pass custom `SliverConstraints` to a `ListView` or other sliver widget.

---

As for answering the question "How can I detect if a widget will overflow its constraints before it is rendered?":

I copied the code for `RenderSliverList` into my own class (`NoCacheRenderSliverList`) and began tweaking things. It should be noted that I used `NeverScrollableScrollPhysics` so that I didn't have to worry about scrolling (because I don't need it).

First off, at the top of the `performLayout` method, I changed the `targetEndScrollOffset` to be the remaining paint extent and not anything to do with the scroll offset or the cache extent. Only concerned with visible area here:

```
final double targetEndScrollOffset = this.constraints.remainingPaintExtent;
```

Next, I need to change the nested `bool advance()` method to return false when the bottom of the child goes beyond the edge of the viewport:

```
  assert(child != null);
  final SliverMultiBoxAdaptorParentData childParentData =
      child.parentData as SliverMultiBoxAdaptorParentData;
  childParentData.layoutOffset = endScrollOffset;
  assert(childParentData.index == index);
  // In the original source, this is assigned directly to endScrollOffset
  final tmp = childScrollOffset(child) + paintExtentOf(child);
  if (tmp > targetEndScrollOffset) {
    return false;
  }
  endScrollOffset = tmp;
  return true;
```

With the above code, we'll still end up showing a single child that extends beyond the viewport. My last change is to ensure that this child is garbage collected:

```
  // Finally count up all the remaining children and label them as garbage.
if (child != null) {
  // By commenting out this line, we ensure the final child is garbage collected.
  // child = childAfter(child);
  while (child != null) {
    trailingGarbage += 1;
    child = childAfter(child);
  }
}
```

And that's all there is to it. If anyone has any improvement or needs clarification I'm happy to update this.